# Debug configurations R error in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

In the (Debug Configurations) menu in Eclipse,after I click on (Debug),it shows me an error: (R cannot be resolved to a variable).Am still new to Eclipse and this error confused me a little bit!

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` is an automatically generated file which contains references to everything you have in your project. The fact it is not resolved may be caused by many reasons. 
Check whether the `gen` folder and and `R.java` file exist. In case not, do the following:

- Clean your project by selecting `Project - Clean`
- if the `R.java` is not created, there can be an error in some XML file, check the console output
- In your code, hover your mouse cursor over your R which should be highlighted red and check if Eclipse offers to import it (in case it does, select the R from your project and not from android package)

Let me know if it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by creating new project and pasting all xml and java codes inside new project. It will recreate `R.java` so problem will solve by this way.